# GCC ICE (segfault) and clang compiles just fine: is this valid code?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet:

```
template<typename...>
struct S;

template<typename R, typename... A, typename... T>
struct S<R(A...), T...> {
    template<R(T::* ...M)(A...)>
    void f() {}
};

struct A { void f() {} };
struct B { void f() {} };

int main() {
    S<void(void), A, B> s;
    s.f<&A::f, &B::f>();
}
```

Clang (3.9) compiles it with no error.
GCC (6.2) has an ICE (actually a *segfault*):

```
/data/user/0/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/temp.c: In function 'int main()':
/data/user/0/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/temp.c:20:23: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
     s.f<&A::f, &B::f>();
                ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

Apart for the fact that I'm already opening an issue to GCC because of the *segfault*, is the code above valid or not?
In other terms, is clang correctly accepting it or should it be rejected by both the compilers?

---

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78216) is the issue opened to GCC.

Comment: it's not because the compiler crashes that your syntax isn't valid, it totally unrelated. You triggered a corner case. Bad luck for you (and good luck to you!). Happens all the time with GNAT Ada compiler for instance.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually I think it's valid code. I only want to be sure or know what's wrong with it. That's all.

Comment: Don't see why it would be invalid, do you have some specific suspicion?

Comment: It takes a while to parse this mentally, but I think it's valid. Still crashes on a recent 7.0.0 build, though.

Comment: @n.m. This line `template<R(T::* ...M)(A...)>`: I'm not sure what's `M` once parameter packs have been unpacked. Set aside `A` that is quite obvious, once `T` has been unpacked, is `M` a pack for itself or I'm trying to do something that is not valid? It's _brain-breaking_, even if I wrote it. I would say it's a parameter pack in `f`, but I'm not sure to be honest.

Comment: @skypjack clang certainly thinks so: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nV7wpiOv0iKIzE9V

Comment: @krzaq As mentioned in the question, I succeeded to compile it with clang 3.9. Anyway, [I've already had problems](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30518) with clang when dealing with parameter packs. So, well, the fact that it compiles the snippet doesn't mean that the latter is valid. That said, do not misunderstand me, I think it's valid actually.

Comment: @skypjack I was responding to your comment about `M`. As you can see under the link, it's a valid pack of member function pointers (they're called there).

Comment: @krzaq Yeah, I got the example, `M` is actually a parameter pack as suspected. At least for clang. And please, trust me, I would have given you a +1 for the 'BARK` macro if it was possible!! :-)

Comment: I don't understand these kind of questions. Do you want us to enumerate each and every relevant paragraph? What explanation classifies as sufficient?

Comment: @Columbo No, unless it is invalid code. In this case, I would like to know why it's invalid (no need to enumerate anything anyway, a brief overview suffices). Otherwise, well, no answer or a comment that says that's valid is already an answer for me. Is it forbidden to have a doubt about a snippet?

Comment: @skypjack I guess I'm just bummed about the fact that there is no satisfying answer, since the code is quite straightforwardly well-formed.

Comment: @Columbo And this one is pretty good an answer, for the fact that it comes from you. :-) That said, if you find the question isn't a good one, I can delete it. No problem, really.

Comment: @skypjack This is certainly not a *bad* question, just one with no good answers. :-)